# Propagation of two non-parallel waves

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, interference

When a transverse wave is described by the equation, $y=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$,it is immediately meant that the direction of propagation is the $x$ axis with $y$ axis as the displacement. And we know every sinosoidal wave has such equation. That means the direction of propagation of all waves *has to be parallel to $x$ axis*. That should mean that the direction of propagation of all waves are parallel. But this is not true. Obviously the direction of propagation of two waves can intersect at a point (as we can see in youngs double slit experiment). This may seem like a extremely silly question but I am really confused by this. Since if we use the equations of the waves,we are inherently assuming that both of their direction of propagation is the $x$ axis. Kindly enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Your wave equation is for one dimension whereas a three dimensional wave would have the $kx$ term replaced by $\vec k\cdot\vec r$ where $\vec r$ is the position vector and $\vec k$ is the wave vector whose direction is perpendicular to the wavefront and in an isotropic medium is the direction of wave propagation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. So,the waves in young double slit experiment,are $2$ dimensional waves where the $kx$ term is replaced by terms containing $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Yes, and for two pinholes, as were used by Young, it becomes a three dimensional problem with the fringes in a plane being hyperbolae.